# Data Validation list only to include every 4 cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to have the data validation of a cell (B9) set to a list of values but only to include the cells B7,B11,B15,B19 from a different sheet.
I do not want the gap values to appear.

Note also, the cells B7,B11,B15,B19 contain formulas hence the list should contain the up to date fromula values.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we want to use the values from a worksheetsheet  called *other*.

Pick a cell, say **D1**,and enter:

```
=other!B7
=other!B11
=other!B15
=other!B19
```

into it and the cells below it.  Then apply *DV* using the little list in **D1** through **D4**:

[image]

This method allows you to pick values from various disjoint sources.

Comment: Thank you. Will this list automatically update when the values of B7,B11,B15,B19 change?

Comment: @EmilyG  ......yes...............

Comment: thank you. could you consider my next question for me if you have time: https://superuser.com/questions/1223996/excel-cover-a-formula-in-drop-down-list-with-a-word

Comment: @EmilyG  I will look later