# Cover a formula in drop down list with a word

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

I have a list in `Sheet2 J3:J7` of calculated values.

I would like to insert it as a drop down list into `Sheet1 B10`, which is simple enough, however:

I want the list to use the words: apple (`J3`), banana (`J4`), grapes (`J5`), orange (`J6`), pineapple (`J7`) rather than the calculated values, *yet* the cell `B10` goes onto be used in other calculations, so although the fruit name will appear - its associated formula needs to, somehow, be in there too, in order to be used in the calculations...

Make sense? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure SuperUser is the place for questions about Microsoft Excel, 
but while we're here...

I think this is a job for `VLOOKUP`.

If your Sheet2 looks like this:

[image: Sheet2]

then you have your drop down only reference the Names list, but anything that uses the calculated values would use a `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP([dropdown cell],Sheet2!$I$3:$J$7,2)
```

Make sure you have `$`s in the table reference part of `VLOOKUP`.

```
Sheet2!***$I$3:$J$7***
```

Here's what Sheet1 might look like, with the drop down, then another cell with the calculated value that corresponds to the selected name from the drop down:

[image: Sheet1]

Full explanation of VLOOKUP from Office: [Excel / Formulas and functions / Reference / VLOOKUP function](http://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Comment: Thank you for this - sorry though i'd seen a lot of posts about excel

Comment: My issue is the value to look up is constantly changing via other formulas

Comment: @EmilyG you need to create a matching table and then use `VLOOKUP`

Comment: @Max: yes, SuperUser seems to be the place for [questions about Microsoft Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)

Answer (score 1):

I think Max has offered fine solution.  The key is that once the user has selected a value to fill **B10**, say *banana*, another cell, say **C10**, can contain a *VLOOKUP()* to retrieve the result of a banana-specific formula.